# The main repository branches link to the corresponding submodule branches

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have two branches master and dev. How to make the master branch of the main repository linked to the master branches of the submodules? Accordingly, the dev branch of the main repository is linked to the dev branches of the submodules.

If I specify a branch in .gitmodules this setting will get into other branches when merge.

```
[submodule "submodule_1"]
     path = submodule_1
     url = https://github.com/testuser/submodule_1.git
     branch = master
```

```
I have the main repository structure:

main_repo
│   ... 
│
└───submodule_1
│   │   ...
│   
└───submodule_2
    │   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Submodules configuration is tracked by git. So if you have different branches/commits for submodules in `dev` and `main`, and you're gonna merge `dev` into `main` for example, then you will have conflicts.

But if your `dev` and `main` are living independently, then simply configure submodules branches in each branch manually. So set for `main` branch submodules to point to theirs `main` branch, and similar setup for `dev` branch. No need to automate it. Again - if you will merge your `dev` and `main`, you will have conflicts - so anyway you will have to resolve those conflicts manually.